# Working out atomic clock accuracy using measured frequency Hz, error and beat Hz

Tags: atomic-physics, frequency, atomic-clocks

I've got a question where $200,000\,{\rm Hz}$ applied to the Cesium atoms and from the mismatch with the atom's natural frequency, we get a "beat" of $2\,{\rm Hz}$.  The error is $1\%$.  The accuracy of the clock is then $1$ in $10,000,000$.

How did they get the $10,000,000$?

My guess is, since $1\%$ of $2\,{\rm Hz}$ is $0.02\,{\rm Hz}$:

$$\frac{0.02\,{\rm Hz}}{200,000\,{\rm Hz}}  = \frac{2}{20,000,000} = \frac{1}{10,000,000}$$

If the beat is $150\,{\rm Hz}$ and error is $0.002\%$ then what is the accuracy of the clock? I'm confused about the frequency applied to the atom, should I reuse the $200,000\,{\rm Hz}$?  The only other frequency is the natural frequency of the Cesium atom - $9200\,{\rm MHz}$.

Comment: I don't understand how you get a beat frequency of 2Hz from a 200kHz EM wave and caesium atoms. This suggests there is some aspect of the question you have omitted.

Comment: I've added the background page and the question page (number #3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example on the first page is a bit confusing because it has nothing to do with caesium. It's giving a hypothetical example of measuring a frequency $F$ against a hypothetical standard 200kHz oscillator. If the beat frequency is $F_b$, the unknown frequency $F$ is given by:

$$ F = 200000 \pm F_b \tag{1} $$

It isn't clear to me how the article resolves the ambiguity or whether to use $+$ or $-$, but let's ignore that for now and assume it's $+$ so $F \approx 200002$ Hz. Anyhow, if the error in measuring $F_b$ is $\Delta F_b$ then equation (1) tells us the error in measuring $F$ will also be $\Delta F_b$ because we assume the 200,000 Hz oscillator has no error. The fractional error is therefore given by:

$$ \frac{\Delta F_b}{F} $$

The article says we can measure $F_b$ to be 2Hz with an error of 1%, i.e. 0.02Hz, so $\Delta F_b = 0.02$ Hz and the fractional error is:

$$ \frac{0.02}{200000} $$

which is 1 in ten million.

Question 3 is doing a similar calculation using caesium as the reference frequency. In that case we have:

$$ F = F_{Cs} + F_b $$

where $F_{Cs}$ is exactly 9,192,631,770 Hz by definition and $F_b$ is 150 Hz. We are told we can measure $F_b$ to 0.002% so the error is $\Delta F_b = 150 \times 0.00002 = 0.003$ Hz.